# Transposing Matrices In A 1-Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix-multiplication

Trying to create a function that transposes a matrix within a given array.

My transpose function looks like this:

```
void transpose(int a[], int rowSize, int colSize){
    int d[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
          int index1 = i*colSize+j;
          int index2 = j*rowSize+i;

          d[index2] = a[index1];
       }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        a[i] = d[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i % colSize == 0) {
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d ", d[i]);
  }
}
```

But given an array/matrix:

```
int c[size] = {
    1,  4,
    2,  3,
    3,  2,
    4,  1 
    };
```

It returns:

```
1 3 4 2
2 4 3 1
```

The desired matrix should look like:

```
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Is it any different from you previous question?

Comment: You mean from my row/column swaps? Yes. Transposing is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is again a same logic. Here if you are using an additional array then it will be something like just the ordered traversal of the array.

```
void transpose(int a[], int colSize, int rowSize) {
    /* int *d = malloc(sizeof(int)*colSize*rowSize);
    if( d == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in malloc");
       exit(1);
    }
    */
    int d[rowSize*colSize];
    int sz=0;
    for(int j=0;j<colSize;j++)
      for(int i=0;i<rowSize;i++)
        {
            d[sz++]=a[i*colSize+j];
        }
    for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
        a[i]=d[i];
    // free(d);
}
```

Few things to comment on the code:-

- Whenever you use `malloc` check it's return type. If nothing is allocated then you will have a guard against blowing up.
- Dynamically allocated memories must be freed once the work is done. It saves you from memory leak.

VLA support is available in C99, C11.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without accessing the memory of it?

Comment: Like how you have d set to malloc(sizeof(int)*colSize*rowSize); Could we just make the array look like int d[number];? Idk if that makes sense.

Comment: @Briehn.: You can do that also

Comment: I got it, thank you, again. Might need your help again for multiplication of matrices as well. haha.

Comment: @Briehn.: I am sure that you can do all this now. You have  coded the solutions ..but had some error. Just use some debugger that way you will do better

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for your index mapping is correct!
Remember `d`'s `colSize` is `a`'s `rowSize`.
So instead of `i % colSize == 0` it should be `i % rowSize == 0` as the new `colSize` for the transposed matrix is `rowSize`.

This is assuming that your parameters: `rowSize` and `colSize` are the row and column sizes of your matrix `a`. And your 1 dimensional indices increase horizontally (along the columns).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// i -> j, j -> i
int index_map_transpose(int i, int j, int transposedColSize) {
    return j * transposedColSize + i;
}

int index_map(int i, int j, int colSize) {
    return i * colSize + j;
}

int *transpose(int m[], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int *t = malloc(rowSize * colSize * sizeof(int));
    if (t == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            // Index (i, j) maps to (j, i) by defintiion of transpose

            int origional = index_map(i, j, colSize);
            int transposed = index_map_transpose(i, j, rowSize);

            t[transposed] = m[origional]; 
        }
    }

    return t;
}


void print_matrix(int m[], int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            if (j > 0) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("%d", m[index_map(i, j, colSize)]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int rowSize = 4; int colSize = 2;
    int a[8] = {1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1};

    print_matrix(a, rowSize, colSize);
    // Prints:
    // 1 4
    // 2 3
    // 3 2
    // 4 1

    printf("Transposing...\n");

    int *t = transpose(a, rowSize, colSize);

    print_matrix(t, colSize, rowSize);
    // Prints:
    // 1 2 3 4
    // 4 3 2 1

    // Remember to free!
    free(t);

    // Another test
    printf("Test 2\n");

    // Test with
    rowSize = 2; colSize = 3;
    int b[6] = { 3, 2, 7, 4, 9, 1 };

    print_matrix(b, rowSize, colSize);
    // Prints
    // 3 2 7
    // 4 9 1

    printf("Transposing...\n");

    t = transpose(b, rowSize, colSize);

    print_matrix(t, colSize, rowSize);
    // Result
    // 3 4
    // 2 9
    // 7 1

    free(t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Filling in the old array with the new values would be no different to the way you've already done it. Just make sure to switch `rowSize` with `colSize`!